# Will Ubuntu work in Dual Boot mode on AMD Ryzen 2500U Processor alsong with Windows 10 Home 64 Edition?

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Acer Aspire 3 Ryzen 5 Quad Core - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/Windows 10 Home) Laptop  (https://www.flipkart.com/acer-aspire-3-ryzen-5-quad-core-4-gb-1-tb-hdd-windows-10-home-a315-41-a315-41g-a315-41-r45r-laptop/p/itmfcfwg7yzqb5sn?affid=hiteshsal1 )
I want to use Ubuntu along with Win 10 Home for Development purpose. Can Ubuntu will work on AMD architecture?
Kindly guide me in this.

Comment: It is easy to try Ubuntu without installing from a USB drive. You are more then welcome to do so.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply. will try it with your suggestion & reply here again..

Comment: Hi all, i tried to install Ubuntu on this laptop but while installing i got error : [3308:68000] watchdog : BUG : sort lockup =cpu0 stucj of r22s and this error was coming for more than 30 minutes. I googled something & found that i need to add nouveau.modeset=0 in GRUB menu. but it did not work. Is there any solution other than this to use Ubuntu on Ryzen based laptop? Kindly help me.